# Localization of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ with respect to the powers of $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

I want to localize  $\mathbb Z_6$  with respect to the powers of $2$. Now if
 $\frac{2}{2} = \frac{a}{b}$, by $c(2a-2b)= 0$ and letting $c=3$ we conclude if $a \neq 0$ then $\frac{a}{b} =1$. Thus $(\mathbb Z_6)_2 \cong \mathbb Z_2$. But my [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=X1ttNRvbNK0C&pg=PA421&lpg=PA421&dq=localization%20of%20Z6&source=bl&ots=PwT3myo610&sig=US1J-zjQWru-51fUPunVW9C_n9M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij8avD6f_LAhVFwBQKHR3SDd8Q6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=localization%20of%20Z6&f=false) says $(\mathbb Z_6[X])_2 \cong \mathbb Z_3[X]$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "Thus"?

Comment: @McFry I mean we only have one nonzero elemnt in the localization because every element is 1.

Comment: Okay, I see. So I checked the definition of localization, and the problem you have here is that 3 is not a power of 2.

Comment: right! thanks. That was a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The localization certainly cannot be $\mathbb{Z}_2$, because $[1]/[1]\ne[2]/[1]$ (where $[x]$ denotes the residue class of $x$ modulo $6$). Indeed, if they were equal, there would exist $n$ such that
$$
[2]^n([2]-[1])=0
$$
but $[2]$ is not nilpotent in $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

---

On the other hand, $[3]/[1]=[6]/[2]=[0]/[1]$. Now note that the canonical map
$$
\mathbb{Z}_6\to \mathbb{Z}_6/[3]\mathbb{Z}_6\cong\mathbb{Z}_3
$$
satisfies the universal property of the localization.